# Code migration for table with many to many relation and extra columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, code-migration

I'll create a table with a many to many relationship between the `ApplicationUser` and an own made class named `Topic`. The table I'll use for holding the up and down votes from an user for a topic so that the user can't vote multiple times to a topic. So my idea is to use a table like show below (⚿ are the primary keys of the table):

```
╔══════════════════════╦════════════════════╦═════════╦════════════════════════╗
║       UserId ⚿      ║      TopicId ⚿    ║   Vote  ║          Time          ║
╠══════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════╣
║ x                    ║ 1                  ║ up      ║ 2016/02/02 15:00:00    ║
║ y                    ║ 2                  ║ up      ║ 2016/02/01 15:00:00    ║
║ y                    ║ 1                  ║ down    ║ 2016/01/01 14:00:00    ║
╚══════════════════════╩════════════════════╩═════════╩════════════════════════╝
            ↓                     ↓              ↓                 ↓           
    Must reference to     Must reference to   Other information about the vote 
  the table where the    the table where my                                   
    users are stored      topic are stored
```

How can I migrate this structure to the database with identity framework? I use also the code first way of working.

Below you can find my `Topic` class and other classes that are extended to that class. The code in the class `ApplictionUser` is unchanged.

```
public class Topic
{
    public int TopicId { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User{ get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime Creation { get; set; }
    public List<Vlag> Flags { get; set; }
    public int? BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    public int? ReactionId { get; set; }
    public Reaction Reaction { get; set; }
}

public class Blog: Topic, IVote
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategorieId { get; set; }
    public Categorie Categorie { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Down { get; set; } 
    public int Up { get; set; }  

    public int CalculateTotal()
    {
        return Up - Down;
    }
}

public class Reactie : Topic, IVote
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Down { get; set; }
    public int Up{ get; set; }
    public Blog OwnerBlog { get; set; }
    public int OwnerBlogId { get; set; }

    public int CalculateTotal()
    {
        return Up - Down;
    }
}

public interface IVote // used for holding the number of up and down votes for a blog 
                       // or reaction.
{
    int Up { get; set; }
    int Down { get; set; }

    int CalculateTotal();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do this:

**Table name:** Votes

| VoteId ⚿ | UserId ↗ | TopicId ↗ | Vote | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | 1 | up | 2016/02/02 15:00:00 |
| 2 | y | 2 | up | 2016/02/01 15:00:00 |
| 3 | y | 1 | down | 2016/01/01 14:00:00 |

**Column information:**

- VoteId ⚿: New primary key of the table
- UserId ↗: References to the table where the users are stored
- TopicId ↗: References to the table where my topic are stored
- Vote and Time: Other information about the vote

**Legend:**

- ⚿ is the primary key
- ↗ are the forgain keys